# LINQ: Compare names (string) of two lists and return List<object> instead of list<string>

Tags: c#, .net, linq, except

I am comparing two lists to find the ones that are missing in one of them.
I have found other articles about this, but I could not find any of them using property comparison, but returning 'the whole object'.

So far I have:

```
return xmlFilesProduction
                .Select(i => i.Name).ToList()
                .Except(xmlFilesRepository
                .Select(x => x.Path.Replace(gitFilePath, ""))).ToArray();
```

For the xmlFilesRepository I first need to manipulate the path, to get the filename.

So far, it works quite all right, however, I do not want to return a list with the names, but a list with the whole object (FileInfo).
Else, I need to loop over the xmlFilesProduction again.

Is this possible? And am I approaching the code above correctly (regarding O(n*m) and various select statements in one LINQ query)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var repoFileNames = xmlFilesRepository
   .Select(x => x.Path.Replace(gitFilePath, string.Empty))
   .ToHashSet();

return xmlFilesProduction.Where(i => !repoFileNames.Contains(i.Name)).ToArray();
```

This will put all the filenames from your "repository" into a [`HashSet<string>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=netcore-3.1) using the [`ToHashSet()` extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tohashset?view=netcore-3.1). `HashSet<T>` is great for checking set membership in constant time. Then it's just a matter of using `.Where()` instead of `.Except()` to filter out "production files" whose `Name` is found in the `repoFileNames` set.

Comment: Or even `.ToHashSet()` to go fully LINQ.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay Even better! Updated.

Comment: Great, this works smooth! So, regarding performance this is also a good option? For example, the xmlFilesRepository contains around 5000 files. I heard recently about the O(n*m) concept, but this is still quite new for me.

Comment: @Robin Can't really comment on performance without benchmarking it, but 5000 doesn't sound like a whole lot. If this isn't actively causing performance issues I wouldn't worry about it.